# Can a user manipulate handlebars helpers?

Tags: frontend, handlebars.js, backend, express-handlebars

My question is about the basic understanding of handlebars.
First of all: Is handlebars operating **front- or backend**?

---

Now to my specific question:
An Example:
I prevent an user from seeing some admin stuff with the Built-in `if` helper

```
{{#if admin}}
    <h1>Welcome Admin</h1>
{{/if}}
```

**Will a user be able to manipulate/bypass this somehow?**

Comment: You can use Handlebars on both the backend and the frontend. If on the backend, the user would not have access to your templates and would not know what logic they contain. If on the frontend, however, your templates must be downloaded to the user's machine and so the user would have access to the logic they contain. As with anything, any data that your users should not be able to access should not be sent to them.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! How can I use them in backend?

Comment: You would need to build an application on Node JS. For example, a very common Node application framework is Express, see: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html